Where do Apple development related questions belong?
I have posted two questions for one problem.
Questions I have posted:

Could someone guide me on how to access and read iCloud email content using API ? If someone can share a guide much appreciated


one question was closed, saying "needs to be more focused"
the other was closed as "needs details or clarity". (Deleted, link for <10k-rep users):


But no one is saying why it doesn't have clarity. If I clarify more, then someone else voted close it as needs to be more focused.

I am not an SME on that topic but one of the things your question potentially misses out on is the programming language / device that you want to use for this purpose. Also have you considered simply using IMAP and SMTP?

@AbdulAzizBarkat - Authors question that wasn’t deleted wasn’t clear or well scoped.

"best approaches" is vague - see https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/142353/160917, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/296542/781723. The question sounds too broad; you may have better luck if you identify one specific thing you are trying to do. Your last sentence is unsuitable; this isn't the site for that.  This site is intended for narrowly scoped problems.  You are more likely to be able to articulate a concrete question if you first do some research, and outline what approaches you've already considered and your requirements in the question. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/781723.

While not every how-to question requires providing code, it is very rare the case where one doesn't benefit from some code, to at least give context and help scope the question adequately.

@SecurityHound if I already have a code why do wouldn't I put the code there and ask question directly, and " zero code " thing that's absurd bcoz there are many questions without any code just simple questions like this.

Maybe the disconnect is that you think this is a "simple question", while the (potential) answers can be incredibly lengthy and complex. Without adequate scoping, it's simply an open-ended request for advice.

@SecurityHound "“guide me to my answer”, isn’t going to be within scope without an honest legitimate attempt by the author" here's a how-to question that has no code, no attempt but is on-topic and well received: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415511/how-do-i-get-the-current-time-in-python The reason I commented there was that one of the reasons people misunderstand needing code for a question to be on-topic is because of comments like these on Meta.

Well, good news: Even more users will get their voting privileges soon!

@pl-jay the problem with your question is that it is not clear enough. 1) What programming language do you want to use? 2) Remove that "best approaches" that's vague, let the answers give whatever approach they have. 3) "Please explain the necessary protocols and security considerations." is unnecessary and lacks focus, just skip that. A simple on-topic question would be: "How do I access iCloud Mail emails programmatically?" (bonus: an answer to that would be: "Use IMAP")

I think it's not a duplicate as it's about specific question, and not asking about what is the reason behind "need more focus"

If you are asking why these questions were closed the way they were, or how to improve them - then why is the title "Where do Apple development related questions belong?"? At best, that doesn't seem to have anything to do with what you're trying to find out; at worst, it comes across as if you think you are being treated poorly because of your choice of development platform rather than anything to do with the questions (I can assure you this is not the case).

You should leave "If someone can share a guide much appreciated" out. This is implied by posting. Stack Overflow is not a forum. Stack Overflow is not recorded conversation; Stack Overflow is knowledge in question and answer form.

Firstly, both posts seem to about the same question. So, I think it's better to edit the first post instead of making a new one that will ask (with other words or not) the same things.
About the first question
The first question asks for a way to get mail, but something very important is missing. If mail servers don't have an API, it's because there is already an API. Protocols IMAP and SMTP let you manage mails.
If you search for "get iCloud mail from Python" in Google, you will see (with your post with all titles it had over the time) post like this that never use the iCloud API, but even success to do what they want with the SMTP protocol. In your case, it's the same behavior, but with IMAP, as explained here.
About the second question
While the first one could be focused, this one has a clear issue: It's opinion-based. Here, you didn't make any search, and just ask for explanation, or "best approach" which are most of the case asking about opinion.
This question could be replace by a quick search with s lot of articles as those one.
Conclusion
Creating the second question was not a good idea. Edit the first after some research was the good idea, and could lead to an answer. Actually, they are just two-line questions which seems too broad.

"If mail servers doesn't have API, it's because there is already an API. Protocol IMAP and SMTP let you manage mails." that's basically an answer. This is exactly why I edited and cast a reopen vote. If there's a suitable duplicate we can close with that as well.

Yes @AbdulAzizBarkat I partially made an answer in this post. And, actually I failed to find a post that could make it as duplicate. I'll vote to reopen then make an answer when it will be opened
